# Make two variables track each other in python

Tags: python

Having two objects (or simple variables), I would like them to be 'bidirectionally observed' or whatever the name should be. The values should track like this:

```
# just some variables
a = 5
b = 4
track(a,b)
a = 3
print(b) --> 3
b = 6
print(a) --> 6
```

Actually, these should be properties of two objects or values of two dictionaries. Or - values of two dictionaries being parts of two objects of different classes.

Even better/worse, the two (different) classes could be using e.g. 
__setitem__/__getitem__ to access the values and do additional computation, which should be triggered when the 'brother' changes:

```
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.d = {'a':3}
  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.d[key] = value
    self.do_magic_computation(key, value)

class B():
  def __init__(self):
    self.d = {'b':3}
  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.d[key] = value
    self.do_another_computation(key, value)


a = A()
b = B()
track(a['a'], b['b'])
a['a'] = 5
print(b['b']) --> 5  (+ magic computation happened in a and b)
```

My idea was the following - do a circular observer pattern and a 'tracker' object that will listen for changes in both *a* and *b*. It would then trigger the 'brother'.

Any idea for some 'magic' python way to accomplish this?

Comment: For the dictionary problem, why not just make `a` and `b` the same dictionary to begin with? (i.e. `a = b = {}`)

Comment: Aha, indeed, that would solve it if it's a simple dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is simply to be able to refer to one mutable location in two or more ways, rather than convenient syntactic sugar for that same functionality, then you could simply use a `list` to achieve it:

```
a = b = [4]
a[0] = 5
print(b[0]) --> 5
```

As should be obvious, you can use this same approach with object attributes and dictionary values and anything else.

To be sure, if what you want is a truly general `track()` function similar to what you actually describe, then that's impossible in Python, since you cannot "pass l-values" to begin with.

Comment: that's pretty nice and not too annoying for a simple variable, any idea for the classes example? BTW. a general track() is not necessary, I had in mind that it is "some operation to tell a and b to track each other"

Comment: @ronszon: I didn't quite understand what was the core part of the classes example. Was it to be able to run some code when the shared value changes, or was it just to be able to share a value through an object's `__setitem__`. In the latter case, that could just as well be done as in the answer as it currently looks.

Comment: Well, both are interesting I think, as the examples increase in complexity. The final example is indeed of having objects of two classes, with variables tracking each other AND code being executed in both objects on change of either variable. For example: two GUI objects with a certain value being "tracked" - gui widget update routine is rerun in each tracked object whenever the tracked variable value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was happily devising some evil solution that should never be used in production, just for the sake of it, when I realized that it is actually impossible to do this magic in python2.7. This answer is to share my failure and why:

So, to do the tracking we need to execute some code on every assignment, to update all other variables, the following line should execute code that updates the other references (`b` in your example):

```
a = 1
```

My first thought was "Well, a variable is actually stored on the locals() or globals() dictionary, so lets try the object protocol with one of these", the problem is that the object protocol does not have a method for assignment.

My second thought was "Hey `a = 1` is syntax sugar for the a dictionary assignment", the dictionary could be either globals() or locals() where the statement would be equivalent to `globals()['a'] = 1` or `locals()['a'] = 1`, we just need some magic on `globals().__setitem__` and `locals().__setitem__` to do the tracking, but both dictionaries are actually wrappers around c code, meaning that we cannot override neither `__setitem__` method, that is not a huge problem because we could use `ctypes` and do some poking, but then I realized that `__setitem__` is never called.

There is a implementation detail, assignments will roughly compile to:

```
1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
            3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
```

and something like:

```
b = c
```

will compile to:

```
4          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
           15 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
           19 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
```

Where [STORE_FAST](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST) and [LOAD_FAST](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST) are cpython optimizations that skip dictionary lookup, instead it will use a `fastlocals` array of pointers. It turns out that `a=1` is not the same as `locals()['a']=1` and there is not a easy hook to call code on asignment.

Comment: Well, that's interesting! So making two simple variables track each other in a 'transparent' way - not possible. I guess the other solutions are not so 'annoying' though, no?

Comment: I said impossible but don't take it too seriously, to be more precise, to do this magic with assignment alone (not using `setattr` or `setitem`) is hard. The problem is that the options are heavy magic, like using a preprocessor, generating your own bytecode or trying to disable the LOAD_FAST / STORE_FAST optimizations, it seems too much effort. I think the use of a mutable collection actually a good solution, but I don't really know if you should be trying to do this at first place.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a class field to achieve it:

```
class A(object):

   fld = {}

   def __init__(self):
       self.d = {'a':3}
   def __setitem__(self, key, value):
       A.fld[key] = value
   def __getitem__(self, key):
    return A.fld[key]

a = A()
b = A()
a['a'] = 5
print a['a']   # prints 5
print b['a']   # prints 5
```

If the objects being tracked are from different classes, you could replace the class variable with a global dictionary:

```
fld = {}

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {'a': 3}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        fld[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return fld[key]


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {'a': 3}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        fld[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return fld[key]

a = A()
b = B()
a['a'] = 5
print a['a']  # prints 5
print b['a']  # prints 5
```

Comment: Good idea, but I need to modify the example to indicate a and b can be of different class

Comment: A global dictionary is nice, though I see here two issues. 1) all objects of classes A and B will be tracking the values, not the chosen objects. 2) the 'magic_computation' does not run in B if there's a change in A...